# Does the Japanese The Last Mission DVD have English subtitles?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter, merchandise

I want to see this movie and I don't want to torrent it, but I don't know where I can buy it  so that I will be able to understand it.

For instance if I buy the DVD listed on Amazon [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JZBPPU0) will it come with English subtitles?

Comment: according to [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=15112) i don't see any companies which have the licences for it outside japan, but the site doesn't say if it had already been subbed

Comment: It's not unheard of for a Japanese release to have English subtitles, but at least in my experience they usually document this in the product information. I don't see any such indication on the [amazon.co.jp page](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B00JZBM4ZE) so my best guess is that there are no subs. But it would be hard to prove this unless someone has the DVD itself and can confirm that there are no English subs.

Comment: If it doesn't have subtitles i'd say still buy the japanese disk and after you get it and validate it's a legit copy torrent/download a version it with subs (chances are they'd be fan subs), how can you be harming the creators at that point?

Comment: @Memor-X that's a good idea I think I'll probably do that.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The Japanese version has no subtitles embedded for English. The only way you could get around this is buy the movie, rip the image, mux in some subtitles, and then re-burn a "backup". This is no advocating doing so -- check your local law.